# how to count the value when search in the array

Tags: php

I need some help with my PHP script. I want to add the value in each time when it add up to each value using `id=row1-VALUE`

Example:

```
row1-1
row1-2
row1-3
..etc
```

Using this code:

```
$program_title = $html->find('li[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext;
```

Here is the full code:

```
$base = $row['links'];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($str);

$channel_name = $_GET['channels'];
$show_id = 1;


$program_title = $html->find('li[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext;
?>
```

Can you please show me an example of how i can add the value next to the `row1-` to count up the value in each time and if the `row1-20` or whatever it is that do not exist then I want to skip it to `row2-1`?

Comment: you can use nested for loop and then use the variable like this `"li[id=row$i-$j]"` where `$i` is the first value and `$j` is the second value you want to add

Comment: @phplover thank you, when i try to use `li[id=row$i-$j]` it would not look for the first value and second value in the array. Any idea?

Comment: this is what i have tried `$program_title = $html->find('li[id=row$i-$j]', 0)->plaintext;`

Comment: use double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Oh thank you very much for that, so how i can create the for loop to find for each value and if the value do not exist then do something?

Comment: Where do you check for the value if it exists or not?

Comment: I use `row1-1` or whatever it is to check for the value if it exists or not. so how i can use the for loop to check for the value if they are exists or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84930/discussion-between-phplover-and-david).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested for loop to accomplish this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++) {
        $program_title = $html->find("li[id=row$i-$j]", 0)->plaintext;
        if (!empty($program_title)) {
            // The value exists
        } else
            break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Replace number 5 with the limit you have for rows.